# How delete tag from node in lxml without tail?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing, lxml

Example:

```
html = <a><b>Text</b>Text2</a>
```

BeautifullSoup code

```
[x.extract() for x in html.findAll(.//b)]
```

in exit we have:

```
html = <a>Text2</a>
```

Lxml code:

```
[bad.getparent().remove(bad) for bad in html.xpath(".//b")]
```

in exit we have:

```
html = <a></a>
```

because lxml think "Text2" it's a tail of `<b></b>`

If we need only text line from join of tags we can use:

```
for bad in raw.xpath(xpath_search):
    bad.text = ''
```

But, how do that without changing text, but remove tags without tail?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question correctly, but perhaps [drop_tag](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.html.HtmlMixin-class.html#drop_tag) might help?

Comment: @phoibos, thanks for answer but no, drop_tag, just remove only self tag and save text inside it, but need some else. We have <a> <b>foo</b>bar</a> if we use drop_tag on <b> result we get <a> foo bar </a> but need in result <a>bar</a>.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit:

#### Please look at @Joshmakers answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47946748/8055036, which is clearly the better one.

I did the following to safe the tail text to the previous sibling or parent.

```
def remove_keeping_tail(self, element):
    """Safe the tail text and then delete the element"""
    self._preserve_tail_before_delete(element)
    element.getparent().remove(element)

def _preserve_tail_before_delete(self, node):
    if node.tail: # preserve the tail
        previous = node.getprevious()
        if previous is not None: # if there is a previous sibling it will get the tail
            if previous.tail is None:
                previous.tail = node.tail
            else:
                previous.tail = previous.tail + node.tail
        else: # The parent get the tail as text
            parent = node.getparent()
            if parent.text is None:
                parent.text = node.tail
            else:
                parent.text = parent.text + node.tail
```

HTH

Answer (score 21):

While the accepted answer from phlou will work, there are easier ways to remove tags without also removing their tails.

If you want to remove a specific element, then the LXML method you are looking for is `drop_tree`.

From the docs:

> Drops the element and all its children. Unlike el.getparent().remove(el) this does not remove the tail text; with drop_tree the tail text is merged with the previous element.

If you want to remove all instances of a specific tag, you can use the `lxml.etree.strip_elements` or `lxml.html.etree.strip_elements` with `with_tail=False`.

> Delete all elements with the provided tag names from a tree or
> subtree.  This will remove the elements and their entire subtree,
> including all their attributes, text content and descendants.  It
> will also remove the tail text of the element unless you
> explicitly set the `with_tail` keyword argument option to False.

So, for the example in the original post:

```
>>> from lxml.html import fragment_fromstring, tostring
>>>
>>> html = fragment_fromstring('<a><b>Text</b>Text2</a>')
>>> for bad in html.xpath('.//b'):
...    bad.drop_tree()
>>> tostring(html, encoding="unicode")
'<a>Text2</a>'
```

or

```
>>> from lxml.html import fragment_fromstring, tostring, etree
>>>
>>> html = fragment_fromstring('<a><b>Text</b>Text2</a>')
>>> etree.strip_elements(html, 'b', with_tail=False)
>>> tostring(html, encoding="unicode")
'<a>Text2</a>'
```

Comment: According to the help of drop_tag it keeps also the text. The result should be:
<a>TextText2</a>

Comment: @TMikonos thanks, I meant  to type `drop_tree` instead of `drop_tag`. I've updated that example.