# python Xpath: how to remove empty tags but keep sibling trailing text?

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

```
<div>
   1
   <br/>
   5
   <p> </p>
   2
</div>
```

Say I have to drop the empty tags.In this example, the empty tag is `<p> </p>`. I create this function to do the job for me. But it also erases `2` after `<p>`tag. So how should I do?

```
def reformat_article(text):
    tree = etree.fromstring(text, parser=etree.HTMLParser(encoding='utf-8'))
    # etree.strip_attributes(tree, 'style')
    etree.strip_tags(tree, 'span', 'font')

    for script in tree.xpath('//script'):
        script.getparent().remove(script)

    for empty in tree.xpath('//*[text() and not(*)]'):
        if re.match(r'^\s+$', ''.join(empty.xpath('./text()'))):
            empty.getparent().remove(empty)

    for empty in tree.xpath('//*[not(self::br) and not(*) and not(normalize-space()) and not(self::text())]'):
        empty.getparent().remove(empty)

    for align in tree.xpath('//*[text()]'):
        s_s = re.compile(r'\s{20,}')
        for line in align.xpath('./text()'):
            if s_s.search(line):
                align.attrib['align'] = 'right'

    text = etree.tostring(tree, encoding='utf-8').decode()
    return text
```

Comment: The trailing text after `<p>` is the element's `tail`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47946748/407651

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To drop an element, without its *tail* string, use the following function:

```
def remove_element(el):
    parent = el.getparent()
    tail = el.tail
    if tail is not None and len(tail.strip()) > 0:
        prev = el.getprevious()
        if prev is not None:
            prev.tail = (prev.tail or '') + el.tail
        else:
            parent.text = (parent.text or '') + el.tail
    parent.remove(el)
```

I tested it the following way:

```
from lxml import etree as et

parser = et.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
txt = '<div>1<br/>5<p> </p>2</div>'
tree = et.XML(txt, parser)
for emp in tree.xpath('//*[text() and not(*)]'):
    remove_element(emp)
print(et.tostring(tree, method='xml', encoding='unicode',
    pretty_print=True).strip())
```

The result I got was:

```
<div>1<br/>52</div>
```